Build Python C extension with cibuildwheel
I try build/compile wheels for lupa under windows. I got one working job in github-action github-action 'manual' for Python 3.6.
I needed replace original setup.py to be able build luajit wheel for windows, line 370 is different:
-or (platform.startswith('win') and 'luajit' in os.path.basename(lua_bundle_path.rstrip(os.sep)))
+or (get_machine() != "AMD64" and  get_machine() != "x86_64" and 'luajit' in os.path.basename(lua_bundle_path.rstrip(os.sep)))

So, I try use cibuildwheel to build for all Pythons 3.6-3.12 but it failed with:
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

I guess key command from manual step is:
python setup.py build_ext -i bdist_wheel --use-bundle --with-cython

Note: It is important (for me) to build luajit21 module (since it the fastest). In manual step I was able to successfully build all modules: luajit21, luajit20, lua54-lua51
When I install lupa-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl from manual job, all imports are working:
import lupa.luajit21
import lupa.luajit20
import lupa.lua54
import lupa.lua53
import lupa.lua52
import lupa.lua51


The trick is add before cibuildwheel job:
- name: "VS setup env"
  uses: TheMrMilchmann/setup-msvc-dev@v3
  with:
    arch: x64

It just run vcvars64.bat and Does nothing on Linux/Mac.
For the record none of is working:

setting CIBW_BEFORE_BUILD_WINDOWS to call C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
setting CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_WINDOWS to call C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat

